# java.lang.illegalArgumentException getting displayed Un-expectedly

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to display list view of all my sub tasks by fetching them from database. I am getting an illegal argument exception. But I am surprised because I am querying a different table and the exception displays some other tables column does not exist. Can any one of please let me know what is happening and what is missing in the code:

My List View code:

```
public void populateListView() {

        SQLiteDataBaseAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataBaseAdapter(this);

        Cursor cursor = adapter.getAllSubTaskData();

        // Log.d("Pana", "The value of cursor is " +Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cursor.toString())));

        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{SQLiteHelper.UIDCHILD, SQLiteHelper.SUB_TASK_NAME};
        int[] toViewIds = new int[]{R.id.textViewNumber, R.id.textViewName};

        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_row, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIds, 0);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSubTask);
        listView.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The position of the item clicked is " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SubTaskDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", Integer.toString(position + 1));  //position starts from 0, but in db row starts from 1
                startActivity(intent);


            }


        });

    }
```

My DB code:

```
public Cursor getAllSubTaskData() {
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {SQLiteHelper.UIDCHILD,
                SQLiteHelper.SUB_TASK_NAME,
                SQLiteHelper.CONTACT_NAME,
                SQLiteHelper.CONTACT_NUMBER,
                //SQLiteHelper.CONTACT_EMAIL,
                SQLiteHelper.DESCRIPTION,
                SQLiteHelper.REMARKS,
                SQLiteHelper.DATE,
                SQLiteHelper.TIME,
                SQLiteHelper.ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_DATE,
                SQLiteHelper.ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME,
                SQLiteHelper.ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE,
                SQLiteHelper.ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME,
                SQLiteHelper.NOTIFY_DATE,
                SQLiteHelper.NOTIFY_TIME};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_CHILD, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        }

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        return cursor;


    }
```

My ADB trace:

```
03-12 18:57:39.189    1502-1502/com.ms.t.tms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ms.t.tms, PID: 1502
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ms.t.tms/com.ms.t.tms.SubTaskList}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:172)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:149)
            at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:91)
            at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:104)
            at com.ms.t.tms.SubTaskList.populateListView(SubTaskList.java:57)
            at com.ms.t.tms.SubTaskList.onCreate(SubTaskList.java:33)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

My DB schema for that table:

```
 public static final String CREATE_TABLE_CHILD = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_CHILD +
            "(" + UIDCHILD + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + SUB_TASK_NAME + " VARCHAR(250)," + CONTACT_NAME + " VARCHAR(250)," + CONTACT_NUMBER + " VARCHAR(250),"
            + CONTACT_EMAIL + " VARCHAR(250)," + DESCRIPTION + " VARCHAR(250), " + REMARKS + " VARCHAR(250),"
            + DATE + " VARCHAR(250)," + TIME + " VARCHAR(250)," + ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_DATE + " VARCHAR(250), " + ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME + " VARCHAR(250), "
            + ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE + " VARCHAR(250), " + ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME + " VARCHAR(250), " + NOTIFY_DATE + " VARCHAR(250), " + NOTIFY_TIME + " VARCHAR(250), " + SUB_TASK_NUMBER + " VARCHAR(250), "
            + " FOREIGN KEY (" + UIDCHILD + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + TASK_NAME + "));";
```

Please let me know what is missing and help me to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ...`, should be  `Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), ...`  (doesn't fix your issue, but is correct usage)

Comment: whats value of variable UIDCHILD

Comment: what is the value of UIDCHILD ?

Comment: Its the id of that table I have declared it as _idchild, There is another table Named DataTable in that table I have declared the id as _id, I am not understanding why this method is pointing to that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the field of `SQLiteHelper.UIDCHILD`. If that field is named as `id` change it to `_id`. Or when you are querying: instead of `id` use `id AS _id`. Listview requires row id to be named as`_id`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes changing it to _id solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To use a cursor that REQUIRES a column called _id,so edit your table creation statement and adding a column called _id(or change UIDCHILD value to '_id').

refer [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your link to the documentation helped a lot. I didn't knew this that a list view should have an _id column. Thank you. Since the above answer has come first I have accepted that. Please do not mind.